# remove my index.php file using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to remove the trailing index.php on my main site using .htaccess file and the following code....

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html?|php[45]?|[aj]spx?)\ HTTPS/
RewriteRule index\.(html?|php[45]?|[aj]spx?)$ https://www.gekkodev.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

But of course it is still not working! I think the problem is my ssl certificate as that code has worked fine on lots of other sites

Any ideas would be greatly accepted!
Many thanks.

- Phillip

Comment: What is it doing instead of working? Is it redirecting incorrectly? Is it not rewriting at all? What example input URL are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RewriteCond` is taking entirely the wrong approach. An HTTPS request is just an HTTP request wrapped in SSL/TLS security - it will *not* contain the string `HTTPS` in the request line, which is what you are checking for.

If you want the rule only to apply to HTTPS requests, just use the `%{HTTPS}` variable, as [listed in the documenation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

(I've seen a lot of rewrite rules testing `%{THE_REQUEST}` recently, and I'm not sure why, as it should really only be used as a last resort when nothing else can work.)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this is how I have done it!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule index\.(html?|php[45]?|[aj]spx?)$ https://www.gekkodev.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Cheers IMSoP